# how to create time period from-to based on current time in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of delivery time options:

- 11am - 2pm
- 3pm - 6pm
- 6pm - 9pm
- 9pm - 11pm

i want to create list of delivery time and excluding the the option that contains the current time.
For example if the current time is **5pm** the list should be like this:

`[6pm - 9pm , 9pm - 11pm]`

How i can achieve this using Flutter/Dart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter the list of delivery time with function **map** and **keyTime** is the mark time for the start of delivery time:

```
var listPeriod = ["11am - 2pm", "3pm - 6pm", "6pm - 9pm", "9pm - 11pm"];
var keyTime = [11, 15, 18, 21];
var currentTime = DateTime.now().hour;

var listFilteredPeriod =  listPeriod.map((period) {
  var index = listPeriod.indexOf(period);
  if (currentTime < keyTime[index]) {
    return period;
  }
}).toList();
```